# Can HumaRobotics/modbus wrapper be used with ROS Kinetic?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to use the wrapper to communicate with a Modbus TCP enabled PLC and thought this could be helpful.

On the corresponding GitHub page

https://github.com/HumaRobotics/modbus/tree/master/modbus

it states that "The scripts have been developed and tested on Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS Indigo and Python 2.7.6"

Can it be used with Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 ? If not ,where should i start to making changes to make it compatible?

**

- UPDATE

**

It can be used with ROS Kinetic. So far no issues!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303378/can-humarobotics/modbus-wrapper-be-used-with-ros-kinetic?/) by [curi_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/37504/curi_ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 166 on 2018-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Can it be used with Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 ?

This may not be the answer you were looking for, but have you tried it?

That is most likely the quickest way to determine if it would work.

Other than asking the original developers, of course.

> If not ,where should i start to making changes to make it compatible?

I don't believe we can answer this, as it would depend completely on any error messages or warnings (or even crashes) you would encounter.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2